# same query twice but different from clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got a stored procedure who containt basically the same query twice.
Ok that's dumb. The reason why I did this is because in one case I use a `LEFT JOIN` on one table and the other time the table is `INNER JOIN`

```
IF @param = 1
BEGIN 
    --SELECT 1 with the INNER JOIN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --SELECT 2 with the LEFT JOIN
END
```

Is there a more graceful way to this?

Comment: Do you have an example of the query? You could possibly use a left join, then add a where condition which effectively excludes the extra items from a left join.

Comment: @tlbignerd well the query is pretty big. The idea is way I have here on the question. I will have a look at your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed a functionnaly of the application around this so I don't really need this anymore.

After a couple of test the solution of tlbignerd in the comments of the question look like the best way of doing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL, build your query in a varchar variable based on different parameters and execute the result at the end.

Comment: Isn't dynamic SQL slower and less secure?

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't use dynamic SQL unless as a last resort. It is definitely slower, since it doesn't get compiled as part of the procedure.

Comment: As a general rule if you can avoid it - avoid it. And in your case i'd use "less graceful" way and keep both queries. But you asked for a more graceful way :) Also Dynamic SQL may help if in the future your queries become more variable based on more paramenters (e.g. WHERE statement is either there or not etc.)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter well for now I use the my ugly way but I was wondering if this could be improved